# how do I find when each of those equation systems have 1 solution/ no solution / inf?

Tags: linear-algebra

https://i.stack.imgur.com/WxRLM.jpg
can someone pls show the way to find when each of those  equation systems(i added a pic ) have 1/0/infinity soloutions ?

Comment: Hi! It would be better to type everything in the post. Links in the future may change.

Comment: Aren't there examples of such questions in your notes or in your textbook? Examples are usually very helpful for answering such questions.